# How to make script look for multiple of the same vowels in one string?

Tags: python, string, char

I am trying to make a script that can count the number of vowels in a string, for example

```
String: sandwich
Number of vowels: 2
```

It works pretty well, except for one point. If I have a word with two or more of the same vowels, e.g. "cheese", the script counts it as one. Does anyone have a fix?

```
points = 0
word = input("Type a word. : ")
vowels = ["a", "e", "y", "u", "i", "o", "A", "E", "Y", "U", "I", "O"]
for char in vowels :
    if char in word:
      points += 1
pointstr = str(points)
print(str("Vowels in word:" + pointstr))
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I see. You are iterating over the vowels. This will only (effectively) find the first one in the input word. You should iterate over the word and check in vowels.

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the word instead of the vowels :)

```
points = 0
word = input("Type a word. : ")
vowels = ["a", "e", "y", "u", "i", "o", "A", "E", "Y", "U", "I", "O"]
for char in word:
    if char in vowels:
      points += 1
pointstr = str(points)
print(str("Vowels in word:" + pointstr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. Instead of looping over the `vowels` first, loop over the `words` and check if that char is part of `vowels`.

Try this :

```
points = 0
word = input("Type a word. : ")
vowels = ["a", "e", "y", "u", "i", "o", "A", "E", "Y", "U", "I", "O"]
for char in word :
    if char in vowels:
      points += 1
pointstr = str(points)
print(str("Vowels in word:" + pointstr))
```